# Delete From Table - Via Form

Tags: php, sql, indexing, sql-delete

I have a HTML table that displays all my table entries. Also in the table is a delete button next to every SQL entry.

I want to be able to delete an entry the user selects. I've made the form to Post `PHP_Self`, and I'm passing in the index `$i` from the while loop as a reference:

```
$i = 0;

while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){

    ?>

    <tr>
        <td>
            <? echo $row['uniqueIdentifier']; ?>
        </td>

        <td>
            <form action="<? echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>" method="post">
                <input type='hidden' name='remove_entrie_ID' value='<? echo $i; ?>' />
                <input type='submit' value='Delete' name='remove_entrie'>
            </form>
        </td>

    </tr>

    <?

    $i++;

}
```

So this is passed to itself, I now want to do a `DELETE WHERE 'INDEX OF TABLE' == $i`, type thing? I don't even know if this is possible.

```
if(isset($_POST['remove_entrie'])){

    $index = $_POST['remove_entrie_ID']
    echo "Index: " . $index;

    //mysqli_query($con, "DELETE FROM Users WHERE INDEX = '$index'");
}
```

I'm basically using the $i to pick out the index of how the table was loaded, and then using that to pick out which row I want to delete. But I have a feeling this can't be done?

I basically want to delete a row the user has selected from the table.

Comment: Sidenote: `INDEX` is a reserved word http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/reserved-words.html either use backticks around it, or give it another name. Also make sure that short open tags are on. If not, change `<?` to `<?php` if you're already facing issues.

Comment: dam you fred, i was just going to post that

Comment: Thank you, thank you vurry mooch. @Dagon That, is not my best **:::ELVIS:::** impersonation, but it's close. Do I still get my sea-gahr?

Comment: Okay, so what would be the best way to remove a row that a user has selected on? how can I reference it? I can't use 'uniqueIdentifier' as, ironically enough, they're some duplicates within the row - and I don't want to remove the wrong one

Comment: You need some way to identify the row uniquely. Why don't you have an auto-incremented primary key in the table?

Comment: What Barmar suggested, plus you can also setup a column as `UNIQUE`. You have a few options.

Comment: @Dagon Now you see why my initial comment was a "sidenote" ;-) Did you manage to patch up your battleship in time for the flotilla parade?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need $i variable. Just make simple modification in your list:

```
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){
?>
<tr>
    <td>
        <? echo $row['uniqueIdentifier']; ?>
    </td>

    <td>
        <form action="" method="post">
            <input type="hidden" name="remove_entrie_ID" value="<? echo $row['uniqueIdentifier']; ?>" />
            <input type="submit" value="Delete" name="remove_entrie">
        </form>
    </td>

</tr>

<?
```

}

It is also good idea to escape specials chars etc in your post variable to avoid sql injection.

Comment: As I mentioned above: I can't use 'uniqueIdentifier' as, ironically enough it's not unique, they're some duplicates within the table - and I don't want to remove the wrong one

Comment: @OliverJones Surely, you must have a column where there isn't a duplicate entry?

Comment: Sorry didn't notice. You can try use your id together with other column in similar way. Just add some other field or fields from your table as delete condition.

Comment: All there is in every row is a timestamp, and an this uniqueId. I can add anything I wanted to - I went ahead and added another one called indexId, and I get the PHP to count how many rows there are, and then increment that value.

Comment: Although .. I dont know if that will work well ... what happens to two uses post to the PHP at exactly the same time, and manage to get the same count value? Then I'm screwed

Comment: Just alter this new column or add new one as autoincrement and it will  work for sure. Don't count it with PHP.

Comment: okay - I'm slightly new at this - so, I've got my indexId column, do I still keep it as an INT? I see a check box called 'A_I' auto increment, so I've ticked that. Now - for my PHP, do I not need to populate this column at all?

Comment: Just change the $row['uniqueIdentifier'] with $row['indexId '] and it will be perfect. If you have some table relations using old key, just keep in mind that they must be deleted using the old one. Try to always have primary index as some unique value in most cases INT/BIGINT etc. is the best choice. In some cases you can also set table unique key as a pair of values. So in this case if you would like to keep yours idea to count indexId with PHP you could set unique key for uniqueIdentifier + indexId.

Comment: *"what happens to two uses post to the PHP at exactly the same time, and manage to get the same count value? Then I'm screwed"* @OliverJones Not if the column's type is set as `UNIQUE`.